# Visual Studio 2012 installer /norestart ignored

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to do a complete unattended install of VS 2012. It works without forcing a reboot on some windows installations but not on others. Here is the command line that I am using:

```
vs_professional.exe /adminfile AdminDeployment.xml /quiet /norestart
```

I install .NET 4.5 before I start the VS 2012 installer. The only change I made to the AdminDeployment.xml is this:

```
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="default" NoWeb="yes"/>
```

We have region specific images for our Windows 7 desktops. The installer works on our North American image without forcing a reboot however it forces a reboot without prompting on our EMEA image whilst installing SQL CE. Here are some messages from the SQL CE log:

> MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:09:942]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU. The assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"' for component '{3FA0170E-227C-37C7-BAC0-64691A992C81}' is in use. You must restart to update the assembly.
>
> MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:10:911]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU. The assembly 'policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32-policy"' for component '{982245D9-F692-3224-BEC0-C642D74C712F}' is in use. You must restart to update the assembly.
>
> MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:11:036]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU -- Installation operation completed successfully.
>
> MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:11:051]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU. Product Version: 4.0.8876.1. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 0.
>
> MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:11:067]: Value of RebootAction property is 
>   MSI (s) (E0:70) [18:32:11:067]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU. Product Version: 4.0.8876.1. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 1.

What is causing Windows to ignore the `/norestart` option in this case? I have looked at trying to pass in some of the parameters that msiexec uses such as `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` [which I find to be a hilarious option] but to no avail.

Why does the SQL CE installer ignore the `/norestart` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (from Microsoft) is that there is a bug in the SQL CE installer. The workaround is to install SQL CE and then install the rest of VS 2012. The defect will be fixed in a future version of VS.

Here is what a sample install for the SSCERuntime would look like:

```
<installer path>\packages\SSCE40\SSCERuntime_x64-enu.exe /q /I REBOOT=R /l*v <log file>
```

Here is the reply from MS:

> Based on our log analysis we identified the Package that’s caused
>   reboot: Applying execute package: ssceruntime_x64_msi, action:
>   Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\E33F355F5E83D93099A732E2ECE02E07818B2696\packages\SSCE40\SSCERuntime_x64-enu.exe,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\E33F355F5E83D93099A732E2ECE02E07818B2696\packages\SSCE40\SSCERuntime_x64-enu.exe"
>   /q /i /l*v The error that causes the system to restart is as mentioned
>   below: MSI (s) (E4:34) [10:16:48:964]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server
>   Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU. The assembly
>   'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'
>   for component '{9DA4DC8A-9731-3F0E-8BD5-FC17CA6848AD}' is in use. You
>   must restart to update the assembly. This is VC++ 2008 dll and it
>   shows an another process acquires a lock on this dll and not allowing
>   it to be updated. We identified that this is a bug with SSCERuntime
>   where it was not authored with ExitCodes to handle such scenario. Our
>   product team is working on it and it would be considered for resolving
>   in the next release of Visual Studio. At present, the work around
>   would be to first install ssceruntime.exe then install VS2012 using
>   the command “vs_professional.exe /adminfile AdminDeployment.xml /quiet
>   /norestart” after excluding the SQLCE component from the
>   AdminDeployment.xml file.